# AngularJS: Error instantiating controller via resolve

Tags: angularjs

I'm issues trying to solve this problem I'm getting while trying to resolve data that needs to be injected to a controller's constructor. The controller is defined as follows...

```
var dashboardCtrl = function ($scope, profile) {
    $scope.profile = profile;
    $scope.fullName = function () {
        if ($scope.profile == null)
            return null;

        return $scope.profile.firstName + " " + $scope.profile.lastName;
    }
}
```

Notice it expects an object (`profile`). This is how the controller is registered...

```
var centralApp = angular.module("centralApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);

centralApp.factory("accountsFactory", accountsFactory);
centralApp .controller("dashboardCtrl", ["$scope", "profile", dashboardCtrl]);
```

The accounts factory simply performs account-related operations on a back-end RESTful service. Then, in the apps' config function I have defined the route as below...

```
var configFunc = function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/dashboard',
            controller: "dashboardCtrl",
            resolve: {
                profile: function (accountsFactory) {
                    return accountsFactory.profile();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

and finally the `accountsFactory` is defined as below...

```
var accountsFactory = function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        profile: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get("https://api.domain.com/profiles/me")
            .success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                deferred.reject(data);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}

accountsFactory.$inject = ["$http", "$q"];
```

Now, what happens is that when the controller is instantiated I get the following error...

> https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=profileProvider
>   Unknown provider: profileProvider

The funny thing is that I can see that `profile` contains the data I'm expecting when I use Chrome's Developer Tools, but Angular still insists that something went wrong

#### The Question(s)

Where does this `profileProvider` come from?
Why can I see on Chrome's Developer Tools that `profile` is indeed instantiated with data?

I have already tried different approaches found on SO but I can't get passed this point.
Any pointers will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to inject `profile` at the point where you create the controller. The router takes care of injecting `profile` from your resolve function.

You don't have a `profileProvider` which is why you get the error. You have a `profile` resolver from the router. While both are injected they are different, the function in your `resolve` is local to that particular state.

You should annotate `profile` on the [dependancy injection property `$inject` of your controller instead](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di):

```
var dashboardCtrl = function ($scope, profile) {
    ...
}

dashboardCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'profile'];
centralApp .controller("dashboardCtrl", ["$scope", dashboardCtrl]);
```

Comment: Damn!! So simple. Cheers mate! Still getting thru this angularjs learning curve :P

Comment: Yeah, we were all there at one point. Once you get your head around Angular's DI everything in Angular clicks :) Good luck with your project.

Comment: actually, this is getting very intriguing...`profile` is coming in undefined while I can see that the api is returning the expected data. Most likely related to something else...out of the scope of this question. Anyway, thanks again scott

Comment: Try injecting your `accountsFactory` into your resolve. i.e. `resolve: { profile: ['accountsFactory', function(accountsFactory) { return accountsFactory.profile() } ]}`

Comment: It turned out to be related to the fact that I was instantiating the controller from the view via `ng-controller` directive...which was actually invoking the controller's constructor twice...when the route changed and when the view was rendered.